# Query date range with Dropbox Datastore

Tags: android, dropbox-api, datastore

I'm attempting to use Dropbox's Android datastore api but I don't see how someone would be able to query a range of values.  For instance, I want to add a date to each `DbxFields` object and I'd like to be able to search for items within a certain date range.  Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All operations in the Datastore API are local, operating on cached data. So the `query` method just performs a local in-memory search. This means there's no downside to just doing the search yourself. You can write a for loop, iterate over everything in the datastore, and just pick out the things you want. This won't be slower than having the SDK do roughly the same thing.